# Turtle not responding IDLE

Tags: turtle-graphics, python-idle

I wrote this code with turtle library. The problem is that when I run this code in IDLE,everything works fine until it gets to the input in the function 'putBall()' ,and the window become 'not responding'.
I tried several suggestions from google like 'turtle.done' in end of code or 'turtle.done' in the end of each one of the functions,but in seems do nothing in both cases.
I want to add that I tried this code in online service 'Trinket' and it work fine.

```
import turtle

def initialize_pen_screen():
  s=turtle.getscreen()
  s.setup(600,600)
  t = turtle.Turtle()
  ballOne = turtle.Turtle()
  ballOne.shape('turtle')
  ballOne.fillcolor("red")
  ballOne.pencolor("red")
  ballTwo = turtle.Turtle()
  ballTwo.shape('turtle')
  ballTwo.fillcolor("blue")
  ballTwo.pencolor("blue")
  t.shape("turtle")
  s.bgcolor("gray")
  return [t,ballOne,ballTwo]

def initialize_pen_screen_saviour():
  t = turtle.Turtle()
  ballOne = turtle.Turtle()
  ballOne.shape('turtle')
  ballOne.fillcolor("red")
  ballOne.pencolor("red")
  ballTwo = turtle.Turtle()
  ballTwo.shape('turtle')
  ballTwo.fillcolor("blue")
  ballTwo.pencolor("blue")
  t.shape("turtle")
  return [t,ballOne,ballTwo]
  
def initialize_first(t,ballOne,ballTwo):
  t.rt(180)
  t.penup()
  t.fd(150)
  t.lt(90)
  t.pensize(10)
  ballOne.lt(90)
  ballOne.penup()
  ballOne.fd(90)
  ballTwo.lt(90)
  ballTwo.penup()
  ballTwo.fd(150)
  ballOne.rt(90)
  ballTwo.rt(90)

#draw line that goes down
def stamp_up(t):
  t.pendown()
  t.stamp()
  t.fd(250) #depends how long column
  #print(t.pos(),'UP')
  t.lt(90)
  t.penup()
  
#draw line that goes up  
def stamp_down(t):
  t.fd(70)
  #print(t.pos(),'Down')
  t.lt(90)
  t.pendown()
  t.stamp()
  t.fd(250) #depends how long column
  t.rt(90)
  t.penup()
  t.fd(70)
  t.rt(90)

#draw ball and save coordinate of reserved position in column   
def move_ball(chosenBall,x,y):
  chosenBall.goto(x+20,y+20)
  chosenBall.fd(15)
  chosenBall.dot(50)
  newClosedPos=[x,y+50]
  chosenBall.goto(0,150)
  return newClosedPos

#put ball in table,and save another reserved position in column  
def putBall(currentMove):
  print("which column to put your ball?")    
  column=input()
  if(column=='1'):
    x=closedColumnOne[len(closedColumnOne)-1][0]
    y=closedColumnOne[len(closedColumnOne)-1][1]
    newClose=move_ball(currentMove,x,y)
    closedColumnOne.append(newClose)
  elif(column=='2'):
    x=closedColumnTwo[len(closedColumnTwo)-1][0]
    y=closedColumnTwo[len(closedColumnTwo)-1][1]
    newClose=move_ball(currentMove,x,y)
    closedColumnTwo.append(newClose)
  elif(column=='3'):
    x=closedColumnThree[len(closedColumnThree)-1][0]
    y=closedColumnThree[len(closedColumnThree)-1][1]
    newClose=move_ball(currentMove,x,y)
    closedColumnThree.append(newClose)
  elif(column=='4'):
    x=closedColumnFour[len(closedColumnFour)-1][0]
    y=closedColumnFour[len(closedColumnFour)-1][1]
    newClose=move_ball(currentMove,x,y)
    closedColumnFour.append(newClose)
  elif(column=='5'):
    x=closedColumnFive[len(closedColumnFive)-1][0]
    y=closedColumnFive[len(closedColumnFive)-1][1]
    newClose=move_ball(currentMove,x,y)
    closedColumnFive.append(newClose)
  return column

#tell state of world after put ball in table
def afterPutBall(SelectedColumn,columnBalls,tableSize,tableBall):
  for k in range(0,tableSize): 
    for i in range(0,tableSize):  
      if(int(SelectedColumn)==k+1 and columnBalls[k][i]==0):
        columnBalls[k][i]=tableBall
        break
    else:
      continue
    break
  return columnBalls

#check if we in a win state 
def checkWin(tableSize,columnBalls):
    for k in range(0,tableSize-1):
      for i in range(0,tableSize-1):
        flagRow=1
        flagColumn=1
        flagDiagonalRight=1
        flagDiagonalLeft=1
        for j in range(0,tableSize-1):
          #row win
          if(columnBalls[j][i]==columnBalls[j+1][i] and columnBalls[j][i]!=0):
               flagRow+=1
          elif(flagRow!=0):
              flagRow=1
          #column win     
          if(columnBalls[i][j]==columnBalls[i][j+1] and columnBalls[i][j]!=0):
               flagColumn+=1
               #print(flagColumn)
          elif(flagColumn!=0):
              flagColumn=1
          #diagonal right
          if(i+j+1<=tableSize-1 and i+j<=tableSize-1 and j+k<=tableSize-1 and j+k+1<=tableSize-1): #end table
            if(columnBalls[j+k][i+j]==columnBalls[j+k+1][i+j+1] and columnBalls[j+k][i+j]!=0):
                flagDiagonalRight+=1
            elif(flagDiagonalRight!=0):
                flagDiagonalRight=1
          #diagonal left
          if(tableSize-j-i-1>=0 and tableSize-j-i-2>=0 and j+k<=tableSize-1 and j+k+1<=tableSize-1): #end table
            if(columnBalls[j+k][tableSize-j-i-1]==columnBalls[j+k+1][tableSize-j-i-2] and columnBalls[j+k][tableSize-j-i-1]!=0):
                flagDiagonalLeft+=1
            elif(flagDiagonalLeft!=0):
                flagDiagonalLeft=1 
          if flagRow==4 or flagColumn==4 or flagDiagonalLeft==4 or flagDiagonalRight==4:
            return True
    
    return False 
    
    
def score_board():
  score=turtle.Turtle()
  score.ht()
  score.color("green")
  #score board
  turtle.pensize(5)
  turtle.speed(6)
  turtle.penup()
  turtle.goto(-250,150)
  turtle.pendown()
  turtle.rt(90)
  for i in range(0,2):
    turtle.fd(100)
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.fd(130)
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.fd(100)
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.fd(150-i*20)
    turtle.lt(90)
  turtle.penup()
  turtle.ht()
  #turtle.setposition(150,100)
  #score write
  score.speed('fastest')
  score.penup()
  score.goto(-250,150)
  score.rt(90)
  score.fd(50)
  score.lt(90)
  score.fd(35)
  return score
  
def write_score(score,redPoints,bluePoints):
  score.clear()
  score.write(str(redPoints)+'-'+str(bluePoints),move=False ,font=("Verdana",
                                    18, "normal"), align="left")

#build table
def build_table(tableSize,table,opponentOne,opponentTwo):
    table.speed(6)
    initialize_first(table,opponentOne,opponentTwo)
    size_iter=int((tableSize-1)/2)
    for i in range(0,size_iter+1):
      stamp_up(table)
      stamp_down(table)
    if(tableSize%2==0): #even size table
        stamp_up(table)
    table.goto(0,250)
    table.lt(90)  
    #tableSize=(2*(i+1)-1)
    
if 'main':
  playAgain='yes'
  s=turtle.getscreen()
  s.setup(1000,1000)
  s.bgcolor("gray")
  score=score_board()
  redPoints=0
  bluePoints=0
  while(playAgain=='yes' or playAgain=='Yes'):
    tools=initialize_pen_screen_saviour()
    table=tools[0]
    opponentOne=tools[1]
    opponentTwo=tools[2]
    closedColumnOne=[[-150.0, -250.0]]
    closedColumnTwo=[[-80.0, -250.0]]
    closedColumnThree=[[-10.0, -250.0]]
    closedColumnFour=[[60.0, -250.0]]
    closedColumnFive=[[130.0, -250.0]]
    tableSize=8
    build_table(tableSize,table,opponentOne,opponentTwo)
    
    #initilize table state balls
    columnBalls=[]
    for i in range(0,tableSize):
      columnBall=[0]*tableSize
      columnBalls.append(columnBall)
    print(columnBalls)  
    myBall='A'
    playAgain='yes'
    #max moves:25
    for i in range(0,25):
      win=False
      print("Player "+myBall+" play now")
      if(myBall=='A'):
        currentMove=opponentOne
        myBall='B'
        tableBall='A'
      else:
        currentMove=opponentTwo
        myBall='A'
        tableBall='B'
      SelectedColumn=putBall(currentMove)
      columnBalls=afterPutBall(SelectedColumn,columnBalls,tableSize,tableBall)
      print(columnBalls)
      win=checkWin(tableSize,columnBalls)
      if(win):
        #update score player blue
        if(tableBall=='B'):
          write_score(score,redPoints,bluePoints+1)
          bluePoints+=1
        #update score player red  
        else:
          write_score(score,redPoints+1,bluePoints)
          redPoints+=1                          
        print('player '+tableBall+' WIN!!')
        print('Do you want to play again?')
        playAgain=input()
        if(playAgain=='no' or playAgain=='No'):
          break
        elif(playAgain=='yes' or playAgain=='Yes'):
          table.reset()
          opponentOne.reset()
          opponentTwo.reset()
          break

  #t.reset()
  #t.clear()
```

Comment: What is the environment you're running IDLE?

Comment: If it worked on Trinket it is something wrong with the program you are using. I recommend that you switch program, I recommend PyCharm and Visual Studio Code. Also posting your entire code is a bad idea. You should only post the problem area.

Comment: @SecretLloyd  Debating editors and IDEs is off-topic for Stackoverflow.  In any case, as my answer explains, Michael's program works fine in IDLE when one clicks on the shell where the prompt is printed and where the answer must be entered.  Besides this, a turtle program should use the turtle input methods.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thank you for the feedback. I am very new to Python and Stack Overflow so I don't always understand things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Lines 80-81 of your code

```
  print("which column to put your ball?")    
  column=input('')
```

print a prompt to the interactive shell and pause the turtle screen while the turtle code waits for a response *entered in the separate shell or terminal window*.  (`column = input('which column'` would do the same.) To enter a column, the user must click on the window with the 'which column' prompt.  One you do so, entering numbers works fine.

A difference between IDLE and other ways from running a Python module is that IDLE sends your code to a separate process, different from the IDLE UI process, for execution.  I believe that this is why clicking on the turtle window gives you the paused message that does not appear when running your code otherwise.  I would have to do more experiements to determine whether this is true for all turtle programs that seek input from the terminal/shell.

In any case, it is not normal for GUI programs to request input from the terminal/shell.  Turtle provides textinput and numinput methods and function.  Try using one of them.

Comment: I understand,I tried textinput method and it's working great,now the window is not freezing,thank you!